# Why is SQL Server service (MSSQLSERVER) not running after turning computer on and off?

Tags: sql-server, service

Lately I've made a Windows update (Windows 10) and now I'm getting this error.
I can start the service in `services.msc`, but after I restart the computer, the service is stopped.

Can anybody help me how to change the service so it does not turn off after turning the computer off?

Comment: Is the service set to automatic startup? If so, do you get any errors in the log related to the service when you boot the machine?

Comment: Yes, it is Automatic but it doesnt work.

Comment: Do you find any entries in "Event Viewer" that would shed some light on this ?? Any errors when the SQL Server service tries to automatically start up?

Comment: *"Yes, it is Automatic but it doesnt work."* Then you need to look at the logs on the server and find out the error for why it didn't start at start up. There *will* be something in there, you just need to find them.